# How to add autocomplete to text input input field in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, wordpress

I am trying to do an autocomplete textbox input field in wordpress. I am using the below code, but it is not working. I'm getting the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#course").autocomplete("get_course_list.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: true,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
</script>
<div id="content">
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <p>
            Course Name <label>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
            <!--input type="button" value="Get Value" /-->
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show server part?

Answer (score -2):

Please Try this,

For me this works...

```
<input type="text" name="course" id="course" autocomplete="off" />
```

please visit this link

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autocomplete